# My laptop doesn't run Ubuntu! Intel USB problem?

Tags: boot, live-usb, laptop, intel, pci

I want to install Ubuntu into my machine, but it won't boot properly no matter what I do. I tried every type of combinations: USB2 and USB3 ports, different flash drives, UEFI and CSM modes, Linux distros, USB utilities (Rufus, Universal USB creator, LiLi) and most of them yield the very same result. I want to install 16.04.1 to get rid of Windows for good.

Machine: This machine came with Windows 10 preinstalled. Changed to 8.1 and now I want to use Ubuntu.

- Packard Bell ENTE69BH 2015 assembly, bought brand new in Feb 2016.
- Intel Core i3-5005U (Broadwell) 2x2.00 GHZ, 4 threads
- InsydeH2O rev
  5.0 (BIOS version 1.25)
- Intel HD 5500 integrated graphics (Mobile Generation V)
- 1x4GB RAM (DDR3L-1600, memtest86+ errors 0)
- Windows 8.1 x64 (CSM)

First of all. I suspect there is something wrong with my USB controller or even worse, my BIOS, because I get this kind of error when booting without `pci=off` flag (cannot use it, you'll see)...

The Live USB menu pops up, and the Try Ubuntu/Install Ubuntu/OEM install entries will always lead to this:

```
0000:00:14.0: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
0000:00:14.0: PCI INT A: no GSI
```

System hangs.

I managed to boot with `pci=conf1`, `pci=conf2` and `pci=off` but then it dumps me at the initramfs prompt without being able to load anything into anywhere (no mounts, no storages) I am trying to get into Ubuntu to try and then install it.

Tried `acpi=noirq`. This is the result:

```
0000:00:14.0: PCI->APIC IRQ transform: INT A -> IRQ 21
```

System hangs.

On my other computers I could boot and install with zero issues, using the same image, stick and tool.

If I try to boot with the acpi=off or noapic flag then I get interrupt issues:

```
0000:00:14.0: sharing IRQ 7 with 0000:00:1c.1
0000:00:14.0: sharing IRQ 7 with 0000:00:1c.2
0000:00:14.0: sharing IRQ 7 with 0000:00:1c.3
```

System hangs.

`lspci` from Windows (external PCIutil command line tools x64):

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 30)
```

Please help me! I still have Windows available. If you need more info, I will be checking here often. Any workaround will help!

I already tried Ubuntu, Lubuntu and Xubuntu, all of them with the versions 14.04, 16.04, 16.04.1 and 16.10. The same result.

EDIT: It turns out that the InsydeH2O 1.25 BIOS had a buggy ACPI Table. Flashed 1.35 BIOS for my laptop and now I can boot any OS that I want.

Comment: FTR, CSM or Compatibility Support Module, is not used very often in AskUbuntu, where it is commonly referred to as "Legacy Mode". You might have more luck with a DVD rather than a USB.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I would try that, but my laptop lacks a DVD drive. I tried with both modes, Legacy and UEFI. My Windows installation runs through the CSM.

Comment: If your bios is set to Legacy mode for Windows then by all means use the same method for Ubuntu installation. Did you follow these instructions to create USB?: [http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows]

Comment: I already tried that. I remark I tried both modes, starting with Legacy. Also tried EFI because I wanted to try Ubuntu to check if everything was working, and then erase Windows from the drive. But anyways, in legacy mode I get the errors above without pci=off, and in EFI I get a black screen instead. With pci=off, both modes function but drop me at initramfs (possibly after starting that  casper (kernel) they cannot handle my drive) Sorry for confusing you so much, but I am not very experienced with Linux in general

Comment: Any boot parameters that can help me to work around this??

Comment: @BenyaminAusensi This seems like a bug that existed quite a while back with 64**-series HP Probook devices. Apparently, the xhci module doesn't load properly in UEFI mode. Try the kernel param "acpi=noirq".  At worst, you may have to compile your own kernel

Comment: Disable `Intel Smart Response in BIOS/UEFI` and see if this helps.

Comment: My BIOS doesn't have any option regarding Intel Smart Response. Also tried to boot with acpi=noirq and acpi=off in both modes. It hangs the computer.

Comment: sometimes Intel RST just show as 'RAID' and you need to change it to 'ACHI' but need to decerate Windows cached drives first.

Comment: Setting the Windows controller to AHCI didn't do anything, except for setting Windows to AHCI. My BIOS lacks an option to change SATA modes. I know the issue is with my XHCI module and it's interrupts.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" etc. to the title. Accepting an answer is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a different laptop Acer Aspire E5-573-P1NH also with "InsydeH20 Rev.5.0" system bios version 1.25. and I have the same problem. I have read here [Ubuntu error message after GRUB " pci 0000:00:14:0: PCI INT A no GSI "](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837860/ubuntu-error-message-after-grub-pci-000000140-pci-int-a-no-gsi) that my laptops BIOS v1.37 will fix the problem but have not checked this yet.

This may be a general problem with early versions of this type of BIOS and you may be lucky and have a fixed version available. Have you updated your BIOS to its latest version?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you my friend. I finally gathered up the courage to update the BIOS of my only laptop. Packard Bell makes it's machines from Acer so I thought that my machine would be compatible with the CRISIS Fn+Esc recovery method. I attempted to flash with this instead of ZRT_135 and the board did boot. Will test a live USB right now.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! It works now, I can say that my EasyNote TE69BH is now happily running Xubuntu 16.04 dualbooted with Windows 10.