# Ubuntu error message after GRUB " pci 0000:00:14:0: PCI INT A no GSI "

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, pci

I have Windows 10 installed on an Acer Aspire E5-573-56KN. Windows 10 is installed in legacy BIOS mode, and I have UEFI disabled, so that I can run other operating systems more easily. I wish to dual boot with Ubuntu MATE 16.04, but have been running into trouble.

First I got just a black screen with a flashing underscore after grub, so I tried nomodeset as a boot parameter. This didn't work, so I tried replacing quiet splash with nosplash. This gave the following screen after GRUB:

[image]

I have also tried Kali Linux and default Ubuntu, both of which give the same screen. Extensive searching has turned up little of value online, but the error message leads me to believe it may be a problem with Linux compatibility with USB 3. All OSs mentioned are the 64-bit versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same trouble, with the same computer... To solve it you juste need to upgrade your BIOS to v1.37 (Check Acer Website)

Comment: One thing I would add though is that it may be necessary for some users to check the BIOS settings after updating. I found that they reset to their default settings, including the UEFI/Legacy setting.